# mudar o título de um Window confirm()

Tags: jquery, html, apache-cordova

Gostaria de saber se de alguma forma eu conseguiria modificar o título de um `window confirm()`, pois estou desenvolvendo um app utilizando **phonegap** e quando chamada esta janela ele me apresenta o título com o nome do meu arquivo html, consigo modificar isto? se sim como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve passar o título como parâmetro, por exemplo:

```
notification.confirm('message',onConfirm,'title','Restart,Exit');
```

ou seja, a ordem dos parâmetros é: Mensagem, função a ser executada no retorno, título e os "Labels" a serem utilizados nos botões.

Answer (score 4):

Você provavelmente está usando o plugin `org.apache.cordova.dialogs`.

```
Users/ft/projectname/platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/notification.js
```

Abre o arquivo `Notification.js` e encontre o trecho abaixo.

```
/**
 * Open a native confirm dialog, with a customizable title and button text.
 * The result that the user selects is returned to the result callback.
 *
 * @param {String} message              Message to print in the body of the alert
 * @param {Function} resultCallback     The callback that is called when user clicks on a button.
 * @param {String} title                Title of the alert dialog (default: Confirm)
 * @param {Array} buttonLabels          Array of the labels of the buttons (default: ['OK', 'Cancel'])
 */
confirm: function(message, resultCallback, title, buttonLabels) {
    var _title = (title || "Confirm");
    var _buttonLabels = (buttonLabels || ["OK", "Cancel"]);

    // Strings are deprecated!
    if (typeof _buttonLabels === 'string') {
        console.log("Notification.confirm(string, function, string, string) is deprecated.  Use Notification.confirm(string, function, string, array).");
    }
```

E remove apenas o "Confirm" e deixa isso em branco:

```
var _title = (title || "Confirm"); -->  var _title = (title || "");
```

E agora vamos ajustar a parte do "Alert", encontre um código parecido e faça:

```
var _title = (title || "Alert"); --> var _title = (title || "");
```

Testei no Android e funcionou lindo, mas não testei com iOS.

Veja e me fala se ajudou.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível, a alternativa seria usar algum tipo de [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples).

Essa limitação é por questões de segurança, uma pessoa mal intencionada poderia alterar a URL mostrada na janela de confirmação por exemplo.

Comment: um modal com um botão que confirmasse minha autenticação né?

Comment: Sim! É bem simples de implementar isso.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia utilizar o `notification.confirm()` do PhoneGap:

```
navigator.notification.confirm(message, confirmCallback, [title], [buttonLabels])
```

Mais detalhes em:

> http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

Answer (score 1):

um modal bem simples de utilizar é o bootbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Minha Página</title>
<!-- CSS dependencies -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Conteúdo. <a class="alerta" href=#>Alerta!</a></p>
<!-- dependências JS  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- código bootbox -->
<script src="./bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".alerta", function(e) {
        bootbox.confirm("Olá Mundo!", function() {
            console.log("Alerta Callback");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Link oficial: http://bootboxjs.com/